All ceiling lights pulsing randomly
We moved into a 1940s house and are having issues with our ceiling lights pulsing randomly. Some specifics:
-All ceiling lights are on the same circuit, lamps plugged into outlets are unaffected.
-Voltage readings: 104V at bathroom light, 115V at living room, etc. All lower than 120. On the outlets which are on a different circuit, i get a normal 120V.
-We upgraded to 200 amp panel but still on old knob and tube wiring.
-PG&E made adjustments but issue persists.
Any idea on what the issue would be?

Does it happen when the furnace, refrigerator or some other appliance turns on?

Just to be certain, do you have any smart lighting kit at all?  Or just normal on/off switches?  Dimmers?

Since it's the ceiling lights and they are all on the same circuit, It could be a loose connection in the main panel at the individual breaker for the circuit or the neutral. Try swapping the load wire to another same size breaker to check the breaker. If those are all good, find the fixtures and switches closest to the breaker that are pulsing and check those connections.
